# Web3j send ether transaction pending forever

Tags: web3j, java

i'm trying to send ether to a smart contract with a specified amount of gas usage, the transaction sending works fine and it propagates to the network but remains pending forever not being executed as i see on rinkeby.etherscan.io. 
The code i use is this:

```
    Web3j web3j= Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://rinkeby.infura.io/ZE3AbqRo2GCvqu1WbY6O"));
    Credentials credentials = WalletUtils.loadCredentials(PASSWORD, WALLET_PATH);
    BigInteger nonce = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount("0x15Ced4F0b7C3fE42D680FD705aE369a9e986EA92", 
            DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send().getTransactionCount();

    //Constructing transaction
    RawTransaction rawTransaction  = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(
            nonce, 
            new BigInteger("300"), 
            new BigInteger("50000"), 
            "0x5A47C8d694F4edb653Ff50139c91994f492C1d1e", 
            new BigInteger("200000000000000000")
    );

    //Signing transaction
    byte[] signedMessage = TransactionEncoder.signMessage(rawTransaction, credentials);
    String hexValue = Numeric.toHexString(signedMessage);


    EthSendTransaction ethSendTransaction = web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(hexValue).sendAsync().get();
    String transactionHash = ethSendTransaction.getTransactionHash();
```

Is there something that i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(nonce, gas price, gas limit, toAddress, value);

Your Gas-Price is too low and remember it is in Wei.

```
BigInteger gasPrice = BigInteger.valueOf(2_000_000_000L);
RawTransaction rawTransaction  = RawTransaction.createEtherTransaction(
        nonce, 
        gasPrice, 
        new BigInteger("50000"), 
        "0x5A47C8d694F4edb653Ff50139c91994f492C1d1e", 
        new BigInteger("200000000000000000")
);
```